# Determining the source of a website slowdown

Tags: networking

I am in the process of assisting a client build a site at ballershoesdb.com.

About 50% of the time that I try to load the site (either load the front end or access the WordPress backend), it takes 20 seconds or more to load a page. I have had various people in different places across the world test the site and most report no issues, though some have occasionally reported significant slowdowns. A test on [Pingdom](https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/ebqvNp/ballershoesdb.com) shows an issue with browser caching but I doubt that is the cause of what I am seeing.

What steps can I take to determine the source of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Generally your approach of running tests with Pingdom (or others, such as Gomez or Catchpoint) can be incredibly helpful to determine problem areas. In my initial assessment, I saw that there was generally a slow response for the scripts and stylesheets coming from your server and it wasn't always the same script causing issues. For instance, sometimes it was bootstrap.js and sometimes not.

The fixes I would recommend to try are:

- Load your content from a CDN
- Use different domain names that rotate (each browser will only open a fixed number of connections to each domain and it varies by browser)
- Put all of your scripts in a single file if possible, and minify them.
- Ensure all of the files you're downloading are needed (you seem to have multiple themes loading.)
- Determine whether you need to load all of the scripts in your HEAD, as this blocks page rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://testmysite.thinkwithgoogle.com/. It tells you, where your site has performance issues and gives you hints on how you can fix them. You can use this as a starting point.

A similar free online tool can also be found at: https://gtmetrix.com/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Websites get taken down and businesses close. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.